Honda EOD 2005 4cylinder
Good evening house, I have Honda 2005 EOD that started with jerking whenever I tried to accelerate to move to another gear but after the first gear, other works well but then suddenly find it difficult to changed from 1 gear to another and the D light blinks and started making noise and even if i put it on D3, the D would also shows blinking while the D3 still on and it would not change to another gear and I tried to heat the sensor a bit and it started working for a while and now stopped completely, pls I need someone to tell me what the problem was so that I won’t be spending unnecessary money cos my Rewire said the problem is gear sensor and am a novice to automatic gear

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
